# Wildfly ActiveMQ Warning: Starting paging on address 'Queue Name'; size is currently: 10,504,042 bytes; max-size-bytes: 10,485,760

Tags: apache-camel, wildfly, wildfly-10, activemq-artemis

Following error we are facing in Wildfly:

```
[org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (default I/O-1) AMQ222038: Starting paging on address 'jms.queue.ImportEmployeesFromBundQueue'; size is currently: 10,504,042 bytes; max-size-bytes: 10,485,760
```

- Camel picks file from SFTP and put single element from XML array to
  queue as single message.
- Suddenly we found that application stopped reading from queue and found above warning only.
- Went to `jboss-cli.sh` and remove all messages using `:remove-messages`

Again started above process but again getting same issue. I have done restart as well as reset build in wildlfly 10.0 server group.

Any idea What more is required in above steps?

Comment: You probably need to configure paging in your broker according to your needs: https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/2.0.0/paging.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change `max-size-bytes` attribute in the `activemq` element in `standalone-full-ha.xml`. Default max-size-bytes `10485760`.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:6.0">
            <server name="default">
                <statistics enabled="${wildfly.messaging-activemq.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}"/>
                <security-setting name="#">
                    <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
                </security-setting>
                <!-- changed max-size-bytes -->
                <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10685760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
                ...
                ...
                ...

            </server>
        </subsystem>
```